# laravel 4 how to handle login post

Tags: post, laravel-4, request

I would like to create an action to handle login POST requests.
I don't know what am i doing wrong but, i can't handle/print any request in my postLogin action.I am newbie in Laravel, maybe i don't understand the concept of Laravel, but request handling([route base request handling](http://laravelbook.com/laravel-user-authentication/)) via routes is so stranger for me.

I would like to process POST data in my controller's action not in routes!

UserController.php

```
  public function postLogin()
  {
     $user = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

     print_r($user);
     exit('1');
  }
```

Routes.php

```
//invoke action to handle post request
Route::post('login','UserController@login');

//render the view
Route::get('user/login', function()
{
  return View::make('user.login');
});
```

login.balde.php

```
     {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'user/login', 'files' => false,'name'=>'postLogin'))}}
    ...
    ..
 {{Form::submit('LogIn',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-lg'));}}
       {{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

routing with Laravel is a very simple, I'll try to explain it and I hope it will not look strange anymore.
let's first make a route like you did:

```
Route::post('login','UserController@login');
```

by this we mean that for every post request to the link "yourWebsiteAddress/login" the function login() in your UserController will be executed. 
So you should have a function login() in the UserController. To test if this function is being called, just return a string:

```
public function login(){
    return 'login is working!';
}
```

or just dump the input

```
public function login(){
    $input = Input::all();
    return dd($input);
}
```

now in your form the url must be and existing route

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) }}
     {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I hope this will be helpful

Comment: Thank you, but my code still dosen't work. I really don't know what is wrong in my code. result: "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." 500 Internal Error

Comment: try to rewrite it again start with the code in the answer and then adapt it to yours, the most important is to be sure the login method is being called then you can change it

Comment: Thank you so much. I misspelled a word in function's name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand but:

In your form is action `user/login` but in route is `login` (from is post request) try change it to `login` and in routes change`login` to `postLogin`

```
// line routes
Route::post('login','UserController@postLogin');

// line login.blade.php
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'files' => false,'name'=>'postLogin'))}}
```